# Установка системы Debian Linux

Tags: linux, debian, grub

У меня была операционная система Windows 10. Затем я скачал Rufus и закинул image на USB флэшку.
Затем с помощью BIOS зашёл в раздел BOOT и запустил Debian оттуда. Прошёл всю установку, хотя в процессе заметил что некоторый окна не открывались(Следовал инструкциям с ютуба и несколько вещей не заметил в своей установке). Затем после того, как все загрузилось у меня начала открывается исключительно командная строка GNU GRUB. Никакого графического интерфейса нет и прочего. Кто-то подсказал мне,что у меня стерся бут лоадер.
Являюсь новичком в этом плане и пока не имею понятия как правильно решить данную проблему.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: После установки появился такой экран. Как я понял это произошло из-за того чтобкогда у меня была винда,схема деления жесткого диска была одна,а на Линуксе она другая.